# Prove that $\cos(x / 2) + \cos(y / 2) - \cos(z / 2) = 4 \sin((\pi - x) / 4)\sin((\pi - y) / 4) \sin ((\pi + z) / 4)$

Tags: trigonometry

Help me prove that

$\cos(x / 2) + \cos(y / 2) - \cos(z / 2) = 4 \sin((\pi - x) / 4) \sin((\pi - y) / 4) \sin ((\pi + z) / 4$

where $x + y + z = \pi$

I've reached $2 \sin((x + z) / 4)  (\cos((x + z) / 4) - \sin((x - z) / 4))$, but I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Maths.SE. [Here's a MathJax Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) which I hope will help you format your question to make it more readible.

Comment: Hi @Hanul, I saw that you are clearing up the questions in "proof theory", which is always welcome. However, you might consider slowing down a bit. What the first page has lots of posts that you just bumped.  Similar issue [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27508/why-so-many-riesz-representation-questions-in-such-short-time)

Comment: @ArcticChar Thanks you for letting me know. I should be careful to modify tags from now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formula,

$$\cos\frac y2-\cos\frac z2=-2\sin\frac{y+z}4\sin\frac{y-z}4$$

Now, $\displaystyle\cos\frac x2=\cos\frac{\pi-(y+z)}2=\sin\frac{y+z}2=2\sin\frac{y+z}4\cos\frac{y+z}4$ (Double Angle formula $\sin2A$)

$$\implies \cos\frac x2+\cos\frac y2-\cos\frac z2=2\sin\frac{y+z}4\cos\frac{y+z}4-2\sin\frac{y+z}4\sin\frac{y-z}4$$

$$=2\sin\frac{y+z}4\left(\cos\frac{y+z}4-\sin\frac{y-z}4\right)$$

$\displaystyle\sin\frac{y-z}4=\cos\left(\frac\pi2-\frac{y-z}4\right)=\cos\left(\frac{x+y+z}2-\frac{y-z}4\right)$

Again apply Prosthaphaeresis formula $\displaystyle\cos C-\cos D$